# SQL Server: How to get previous data

Tags: t-sql

I know that **LEAD & LAG functions** are there to achieve the task to get previous & next data row. my question is how to achieve the same goal in old sql server where LEAD & LAG not present. please suggest some good approach to retrieve Previous & Next data row with **LEAD & LAG function**. Thanks

```
Here i am sharing one example which is working fine.

Create table #test
  (
  ID int identity(1,1),
  Quarter nvarchar(20)
  )
  insert into #test values
  ('1Q 2010'),
   ('2Q 2010'),
    ('3Q 2010'),
     ('4Q 2010'),
   ('FY 2010')
 select * from #test
    
 select PrevID,PrevQuarter,CurrID,CurrQuarter
 from 
 (
 select Lag(ID,1) over(order by ID)PrevID ,LAG(Quarter,1)over(order by ID)PrevQuarter,
 ID as CurrID,Quarter as CurrQuarter 
 from #test
 )t
 where CurrID=4
```

Comment: Aren't LAG and LEAD already supported in SQL Server 2012? If you're really using SQL Server 2008 or older, you really should consider upgrading

Comment: Aside: If your sample data is extended to multiple years you probably won't get the desired results from `lead`/`lag` since all of the "1Q" quarters will come first, ..., with all of the fiscal years bringing up the tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use correlated `TOP` subqueries in lieu of `LEAD` and `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT PrevID, PrevQuarter, CurrID, CurrQuarter
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM #test t2
         WHERE t2.ID < t1.ID ORDER BY t2.ID DESC) PrevID,
        (SELECT TOP 1 Quarter FROM #test t2
         WHERE t2.ID < t1.ID ORDER BY t2.ID DESC) PrevQuarter,
        ID AS CurrID, Quarter AS CurrQuarter
    FROM #test t1
) t
WHERE CurrID = 4;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4705d0042d32a45a8d8a7cf73da919e).

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do it. Here are 2

Self Join:

If ID is not continuous, use row_number() to generate one

```
select  p.ID as PrevID, p.Quarter as PrevQuarter, 
        c.ID as CurrID, c.Quarter as CurrQuarter
from    #test c
        left join #test p on c.ID = p.ID + 1
where   c.ID = 4
```

using `APPLY()`:

```
select p.ID as PrevID, p.Quarter as PrevQuarter, 
       c.ID as CurrID, c.Quarter as CurrQuarter
from   #test c
       outer apply
       (
           select top 1 ID, Quarter
           from   #test x
           where  x.ID < c.ID
           order by x.ID desc
       ) p
where c.ID = 4
```